# How to insert line break in string -Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to insert line breaks inside a string. Basically I want something like:

```
var result = "Steps to create a account \n 1. Enter your preferred username \n 2. enter your password \n 3. Enter your email address \n 4. click on OK".

<div>{result}</div>
```

But this does not work as it inserts the \n as well, I tried with 
 as well, but no use. any other idea?

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7z1xshj6/

Comment: Your fiddle does not contain any javascript. Did you mean `\r\n` or `<br />`?

Comment: There is no logic in your fiddle, nor your question.  The fiddle has literal `\n` in the markup, not new lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you hardcode it in the HTML, it won't be rendered as newlines, if you set through something like `innerText`, it will work (although with HTML, it's better to use `<br>` (line-break) tags and `innerHTML`, since multiple `\n` will just be ignored):

```js
var result = "Steps to create a account \n 1. Enter your preferred username \n 2. enter your password \n 3. Enter your email address \n 4. click on OK";

document.getElementById("result").innerText = result;
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```